# If-Then-Else code that Locks / Unlocks cells keeps failing

Tags: vba, excel

Using: Excel 2010

This portion of my code keeps failing and I am not sure why. When I try running the entire code block, it returns "Run-time error '1004': Unable to set the Locked property of the Range class".

```
'Lock/unlock issue
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Dashboard").Activate
    ActiveSheet.Unprotect Password:="my password"
    Selection.Locked = False
    Selection.FormulaHidden = False
    If Range("D20").Value <> "Document Recorded" Then Range("F24").Locked = True Else Range("F24").Locked = False
    ActiveSheet.Protect Password:="my password", DrawingObjects:=True, Contents:=True, Scenarios:=True
```

Basically, I am trying to say: If cell D20 does not equal "Document Recorded" then lock cell F24, otherwise unlock cell F24.

Comment: If the sheet is protected then you need to unprotect it to change the "Locked" status

Comment: @TimWilliams I am (or at least, I believe I am) unlocking the worksheet first. Let me amend my post to include the block of code. I greatly appreciate your feedback.

Comment: If you try unprotecting the cell manually, do you still get an error? If so then it's a simple matter of the sheet being protected.

Comment: You may also be running in to conflicts by relying on `Selection` object. Are you sure that the `Selection` is what you think it is?

Comment: this code works as is for me. I tested both cases. You can definitely make it more efficient by working directly with the sheet / range objects and removing the selects.

Comment: I don't know if you can do single line `If` statements. Break that up into a normal `If()` block (adding `End If`) and see if that works. I don't have the chance to test right now...

Comment: @BruceWayne - I can save you the time. The `IF` statement is good as is.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

While I tested your code and it worked as is, I suggest refactoring your code to the following.

```
With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Dashboard")

    .Unprotect Password:="my password"
    .Range("F24").Locked = .Range("D20").Value <> "Document Recorded"
    .Protect Password:="my password", DrawingObjects:=True, Contents:=True, Scenarios:=True

End With
```

Working *directly* with the objects and [avoiding 'Select' and 'ActiveSheet/Workbook/Cell'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba-macros) is best practice and if used can lead to all kinds of unsuspecting issues.

Comment: Also using boolean expressions (as you've done) in place of `If/Then/Else` statements usually yields more concise code.

Comment: I like how you did the `.locked` statement, pretty snazzy.

Comment: Wow, I agree, really like the boolean expression. Seems like it'd be more efficient than the if/then/else statement too. This worked for me, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You have to turn the sheet protection off before you run the code.  I'm assuming your using protection otherwise you wouldn't be using the cell lock feature.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback, Darrell. You are correct about Protecting the worksheet, but I am unlocking the worksheet prior to that code snippet being run, I believe. I edited my post to include the entire code block. Maybe the issue is found there.

Comment: It worked for me, but the only unknown is what cell/object you are selecting with Selection.Locked=False.  Once you activate the sheet the code you are using whatever selection you ended up with last time you accessed the sheet.